# Using decorator in a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For understanding decorators in Python, i created in a class an example. But when i run it i receive an error.

```
class Operation:

    def __init__(self, groupe):
        self.__groupe = groupe

    @property
    def groupe(self):
        return self.__groupe

    @groupe.setter
    def groupe(self, value):
        self.__groupe = value

    def addition(self, func_goodbye):
        ln_house = len('house')
        ln_school = len('school')
        add = ln_house + ln_school
        print('The result is :' + str(add))
        return func_goodbye

    @addition
    def goodbye(self):
        print('Goodbye people !!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Operation('Student')
    p1.goodbye()
```

I receive this error :

*Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Operation.py", line 1, in 
        class Operation:
      File "Operation.py", line 21, in Operation
        @addition
    TypeError: addition() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func_goodbye'*

Comment: addition(self, func_goodbye) requires the parameter func_goodbye which is no given.

Comment: Moreover, why are you calling your decorator method directly? Shouldn't you be calling `goodbye`?

Comment: Side note: using properties in this way is an bad practice in Python. Properties are meant for implementing functionality without breaking attribute access. They have no benefit as trivial "getters" and "settters". Likewise, there is no reason to use double-underscored names here. Double-underscored names are for name mangling with inheritance, [*not* for hiding attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

Comment: As an aside, your `groupe` property is **completely pointless** and defeat the entire purpose of `property`. Just delete them and use a normal, `groupe` attribute.

Comment: It seems to me that we cannot have our own decorator in a class !!! Is it true ?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yes, and you shouldn't learn to use `property` incorrectly.

Comment: @QDex of course you can. The problem is you've defined your `addition` as an instance method, but you aren't calling it from an instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a class scoped decorator, however there won't be a `self` when the decorator is called

a decorator:

```py
@foo
def bar(): ...
```

is roughly equivalent to

```py
def bar(): ...
bar = foo(bar)
```

in your particular example, if you remove the `self` parameter, it should function as you expect:

```py
    def addition(func_goodbye):
        ln_house = len('house')
        ln_school = len('school')
        add = ln_house + ln_school
        print('The result is :' + str(add))
        return func_goodbye

    @addition
    def goodbye(self):
        print('Goodbye people !!')
```

for good measure, I might `del addition` after that just to ensure it isn't accidentally called later

(an aside: one unfortunate side-effect of this is many linters and type checkers will consider this "odd" so I've yet to find a way to appease them (for example `mypy`))

Comment: The way to appease them is to not put things in the class scope that shouldn't be there. You could also use the `@staticmethod` decorator, but really, this decorator should just be in the module-level scope. Upvoted, though.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga do you have anything to back your opinions?  it might make sense (for example) from a design perspective to have a private decorator that knows things about the class internals -- you'd have an equivalent linter problem as you try and modify those internals and (at least to me) a decorator defined in the class body makes a lot of sense in that case

Comment: Perhaps a `@classmethod` in that case, however, in this case, the function explicitly doesn't use any internal state, so it shouldn't be part of the class.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga easily, here's [an example](https://i.fluffy.cc/m62jD0PRprDgGcPW7jtmZ5gfl07685MF.html)

Comment: @classmethod doesn't help for this, there's no class at the time you'd want to run the decorator (`NameError: <classname> is not defined`), and @staticmethod doesn't work either as it makes a descriptor (`staticmethod is not callable`)

Comment: If i realy understand, 1) a decorator must start with a _ 2) It's not necessary to have self parameter. That's correct ?

Comment: @QDex the single-underscore is irrelevant. And you cannot have a parameter if you aren't passing anything to it, or using it as a method. So you *can't* use a `self` parameter

Comment: @AnthonySottile yes, good point about the static methods. Although, the classmethod would fail for the same reason as the staticmethod, both return non-callable objects. In any case, the decorator you've shown could easily exist in the module scope.  As you said, you'd probably want to `del` it after to prevent it's use! In this case, i'd just create a custom callable for the decorator, or just define the function in the module scope. The single underscore serves the same purpose there.

Comment: it could exist, yes -- but a linter is just as likely to complain about the odd signature of the function in the class body as it is to complain about accessing / mutating an underscored variable.